# Não estou conseguindo pegar lista de uma API

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Essa URL funciona no postman: http://localhost:56137/api/GetCidade. Preciso agora em um outro projeto MVC trazer a lista de cidades. Quando eu faço isso eu pego esse erro:

> O item de modelo inserido no dicionário é do
>   tipo'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TreinamentoCrud.Models.Cidade]]',
>   mas esse dicionário requer um item do tipo
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TreinamentoCrud.Services.GetCidadesAsync]'.

No debug eu chego na controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    GetCidadesAsync cidadeAsync = new GetCidadesAsync();
    var model = cidadeAsync.GetCidades();
    return View(model);
}
```

E também a partir dessa controller, eu chego a GetCidades()

```
public class GetCidadesAsync
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient(); 
        public async Task<List<Cidade>> GetCidades()
        {
            string url = $"http://localhost:56137/api/GetCidade";
            var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
            var _cidade = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Cidade>>(response);

            return _cidade.ToList();
        }
    }
```

Quando chega nessa linha: `var response = await client.GetStringAsync(url);`, ele abre o método em meu projeto que está em outro projeto, outra solution. Esse é o método que está em outra solution

```
[RoutePrefix("api/[controller]")]
    public class GetCidadeController : ApiController
    {
        GetCidade getCidades = new GetCidade();

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Cidade> GetCidadesAsync()
        {
            return getCidades.GetCidades().AsEnumerable().ToList();
        }

    }
```

Essa é controller que pega a relação de cidades do banco. O método em minha API para pegar do banco a lista

```
public class GetCidade
    {
        BancoContext banco = new BancoContext();  
        public List<Cidade> GetCidades()
        {
            return banco.Database.SqlQuery<Cidade>("sp_cons_cidade").ToList();
        }
    }
```

Minha Model

```
public class Cidade
{
  [Key]
  public int id { get; set; }
  [Required]         
  public String nome { get; set; }
}
```

Por que estou tendo esse erro?

**EDIT1**

Alterei a model do cshtml e agora veio esse erro

> O item de modelo inserido no dicionário é do
>   tipo'System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TreinamentoCrud.Models.Cidade]]',
>   mas esse dicionário requer um item do tipo
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[TreinamentoCrud.Models.Cidade]'.

Praticamente a mesma coisa, exceto que estão apontando para o mesmo lugar **TreinamentoCrud.Models.Cidade**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu controler da `Index`, troque o retorno do método para um `Task<ActionResult>` e use o await para aguardar o retorno do método `GetCidades`, pois esse método retorna uma `Task` e não uma coleção de `Cidade` (como diz a mensagem de erro):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    GetCidadesAsync cidadeAsync = new GetCidadesAsync();
    var model = await cidadeAsync.GetCidades();
    return View(model);
}
```

É importante sempre ficar atento ao retornar uma `Task`, pois de alguma maneira, vc deve retornar essa tarefa e aguardar o fim dela para ter acesso ao objeto resultado. E é o que o `await` faz